# How can i write this CSS Flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

*How can I write this CSS Flexbox layout?*
[image: CSS Flexbox layout]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try building it yourself. If/when you get stuck, post your code here with a description of the problem and we'll try to help you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer service, not a "from the ground up" code writing service. Here are some more guidelines:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: nothing I'm aware of will handle the box on left matching height of other four within same row container. is it possible?

Comment: It's definitely possible with flexbox. Look into nested flexboxes. You'll need to make the top right and bottom left flex items into flex containers, as well. You'll need `flex-wrap: wrap`. Good luck.

Comment: nested grids. on it. Mike McCaughan, rude.

Answer (score 2):

Nailed it by using nested grids.

[Screenshot - Click image to view full size.[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IELO4.png)]

*MARKUP and CSS here:*

```
        <div class="flex flex-twin">
            <div class="box double">first box</div><!-- end box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="flex flex-twin">
                    <div class="box">second</div><!-- end box -->
                    <div class="box">third</div><!-- end box -->
                </div><!-- end flex-twin -->
                <div class="flex flex-twin">
                    <div class="box">fourth</div><!-- end sub box -->
                    <div class="box">fifth</div><!-- end sub box -->
                </div><!-- end flex-twin -->
            </div><!-- end box -->
        </div><!-- end flex-twin -->

        <style>
            .flex {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                &.flex-twin {
                    .box {
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 200px;
                        background: #ccc;
                        &.double {
                            height: 400px;
                        }
                        .flex {
                            &.flex-twin {
                                .box {
                                    background: #aaa;
                                } // end box
                            }  // end flex-twin
                            .box {

                            } // end box
                        } // end flex
                    } // end box
                } // end flex-twin
                .box {

                } // end box
            } // end flex
        </style>
```